# Finding a suitable function $f$ not to be Riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Given, $f:[\frac{1}{2},2] \to \mathbb{R} $ a strictly increasing function.

Let, $g(x)=f(x)+f(\frac{1}{x})$ ,$\forall x \in [1,2]$

**(1)** there is a suitable $f$ such that $U(P,g)=L(P,g)$, where $U(P,g)$ is upper Riemann sum and $L(P,g)$ is lower Riemann sum.

**(2)** there is suitable $f$ such that $U(P,g)\neq L(P,g)$

Option **(1)** is clearly true by taking $f=x$.

But what about option **(2)**?

As, $f$ is strictly increasing, it can have atmost countable number of discontinies.

So, then, $g(x)$ also have atmost countable number of discontinies $\implies$ $g$ is Riemann integrable.

But, I don't understand,how  option **(2)** is given as true in answer?

**Edit** : in comment, I have seen option **(1)** is true only if $f$ is constant. But, $f$ is strictly increasing, so, $f$ can't be constant. But option  **(1)** is also given as true in answer.

Please help me by giving an example so that option **(1)** is also true.

Comment: As an exercise you can prove that if $U(P, f) =L(P, f) $ even for just one partition $P$ then $f$ is a constant.

Comment: By the way option 1) talks of $g$ and not $f$. You can find strictly increasing $f$ which makes $g$ constant. So in this case official key is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if $f(x)=x$, then $f(x)=x+\frac1x$, which is strictly increasing on $[1,2]$. Therefore, for *any* partition $P$ of $[1,2]$, $L(P,g)<U(P,g)$. This shows that the first option is false and that the second option is true.

Comment: For a Riemann integrable function $g$ , $U(P,g)=L(P,g)$ . As, $x+\frac{1}{x}$ continuous on $[1,2]$, it is Riemann integrable.

Comment: For you, what do $U(P,g)$ and $L(P,g)$ mean and what is $P$?

Comment: Sir, I have already said in question. And $P $ is a partition.

Comment: If $f(x)=x$, which is continuous, and $P=\{1,2\}$, which is a partition of $[1,2]$, then $L(P,f)=1$ and $U(P,f)=2$. So, why do you claim that $L(P,f)=U(P,f)$?

Comment: Whenever a function is Riemann integrable then upper Riemann sum and lower Riemann sum for $f$ corresponding to a partition $P$ always equal.

Comment: Look again at my example from the previous comment. Since $L(P,f)=\inf_{x\in[1,2]}x=1$ and $U(P,f)=\sup_{x\in[1,2]}x=2$, $L(P,f)<U(P,f)$. Where are the errors in my computations?

Comment: I think option **(2)** doesn't depend on that particular partition $P$ for which $g$ become Riemann integrable, that's where I made mistake, I think . If I take any random partition, for which the function is not Riemann integrable, then option **(2)** becomes true. Right??

Comment: Again, where are the errors in my computations?

Comment: No, sir. There is no error. I thought we have to go always with the partition for which the function is Riemann integrable in this question. That's why I made a mistake. Sir, a last question, whenever $f(x)$ have countable number of discontinies then $f(1/x)$ must have countable number of discontinies, is it really always true?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Comment: @Alearner: please note that for Riemann integrable functions it is necessary and sufficient that the **limit** of upper and lower sums $U(P, f), L(P, f) $ coincide. This is not the same as saying that upper and lower sums are equal for some $P$. In fact in general one should not expect them to be equal unless the function is constant.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh : thanks, for that information!!

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: option **(1)** is also true , but you said, $U(P,f)\neq L(P,f)$ unless $f$ is constant. And, $f$ is strictly increasing, $f$ can't be constant, so, option **(1)** becomes false. Then is the given answer wrong?  But,this is a official answer of CSIR NET held in India.

Comment: @Alearner If $f(x)=\log(x)$, then $g(x)=0$ and therefore $U(P,g)=L(P,g)$ for every partion $P$. I can add this to my answer, if you want.

Comment: No, it's ok. Thank you!!

Comment: @Alearner: think of it. If $f$ is strictly increasing then each term $m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$ in $L(P, f) $ is strictly less than corresponding term $M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$ in $U(P, f) $ as $m_i<M_i$. So obviously $L(P, f) <U(P, f) $. Official answers keys can be wrong. Csir gives the option of notifying them of any errors within suitable time frame. However I don't think they give any rewards for this.

Comment: @Alearner: luckily mathematics is one subject where it is much easier not to trust any authority. You can easily convince people of such errors.